# Change text color inside a ListView

Tags: android, listview, textview, textcolor

I'm creating a game and here's the code I'm using to show a list of games with the user names, score, date etc. But how do I get the values of the TextViews tv_playerScore and tv_opponentScore so I can compare them and change the textColors of them? Because what I want is to parseInt and see which has the highest value and set its textcolor to green, and the others textcolor to red.

```
private void showGames(JSONArray games) throws JSONException {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < games.length(); i++) {

        map.put("challenger", games.getJSONObject(i).getString("challengerName"));
        map.put("active", games.getJSONObject(i).getString("active"));
        map.put("opponent", games.getJSONObject(i).getString("opponentName"));
        map.put("date", games.getJSONObject(i).getString("date"));
        map.put("gameID", games.getJSONObject(i).getString("gameID"));
        map.put("amount", games.getJSONObject(i).getString("amount"));
        map.put("playerScore", games.getJSONObject(i).getString("challengerScore"));
        map.put("opponentScore", games.getJSONObject(i).getString("opponentScore"));


        if (Integer.parseInt(games.getJSONObject(i).getString("active")) == 2) {

            mylist.add(map);
        }

        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

    SimpleAdapter sadapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.list, new String[] 
            {"amount", "active", "gameID", "challenger", "opponent", "date", "playerScore", "opponentScore"},
            new int[] {R.id.tv_amount, R.id.tv_activte, R.id.tv_gameID, R.id.tv_player, R.id.tv_opponent, R.id.tv_date, R.id.tv_playerScore, R.id.tv_opponentScore}); 


    listView.setAdapter(sadapter);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the values ​​of a textview must use findViewById function from Activity.

```
TextView tv_playerScore = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tv_playerScore);
```

If the showGames() method is not a class that inherits from Activity (or similiar), you should make a setter injection of the elements of sight to those who want to access.

To compare:

```
tv_playerScore.getText().toString().compareTo(tv_opponentScore.getText().toString());
```

Finally, to change the color:

```
tv_playerScore.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a closer look in how ListViews work ( http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html )

In short I guess you'll have to write your own Adpater class (e.g. extend SimpleAdapater) and write over its getView method. Here you can set the color of the textviews depending on the according value. (I think it would make sense to have them sorted before instead of checking them every time a list element is drawn...